# C# How to have a single Console.ReadLine alter multiple integers

Tags: c#

I'm new to coding and wanted to script a short game to practice while I'm learning. I'm currently stuck trying to figure out how to have a single text input by the user alter multiple variables. Below is the code thus far:

```
Console.WriteLine("Assign SPECIAL points.Note that SPECIAL points cannot be changed once added:");
        int SPECIALpoints;
        SPECIALpoints = 12;
        int ST; ST = 5;
        int PE; PE = 5;
        int EN; EN = 5;
        int CH; CH = 5;
        int IN; IN = 5;
        int AG; AG = 5;
        int LU; LU = 5;

        while (SPECIALpoints > 0)
            {
            /*    Console.WriteLine("Current STRENGTH: {0}. Adjust points: ", ST);
                ST = ST + Console.ReadLine(), SPECIALpoints = SPECIALpoints - Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Available points: {0}", SPECIALpoints);
                */
                Console.WriteLine("Current PERCEPTION: {0}. Adjust points: ", PE);
                PE = PE + Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Current ENDURANCE: {0}. Adjust points: ", EN);
                EN = PE + Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Current CHARISMA: {0}. Adjust points: ", CH);
                CH = CH + Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Current INTELLIGENCE: {0}. Adjust points: ", IN);
                IN = IN + Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("current AGILITY: {0}. Adjust points: ", AG);
                AG = AG + Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Current LUCK: . Adjust points: ", LU);
                LU = LU + Console.ReadLine();
```

Also, I'm getting a CS0029, "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'," but I can't figure out where I ever had the integers every listed as strings.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: use `int.TryParse`.

Comment: fyi, you don't need to do this: `int ST; ST = 5;`. You can just do this: `int ST = 5;`

Comment: "`I can't figure out where I've ever had integers listed as strings.`" You don't. It's complaining about the opposite: strings treated as integer. This is because `Console.ReadLine()` returns a string. You need to `Convert()` or `Parse()` that string value.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I'm going to use the convert() method as listed below. Is there a quick and easy way for the input to adjust both integers at the same time? My current method isn't working. Not sure if I just haven't learned how to do it yet, or if I just have a type somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Console.ReadLine() returns a string value, you're going to want to change all instances of ReadLime to:

```
Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())
```

Note that this assumes your client will input something C# knows to interpret as an integer. If input is given that doesn't match (e.g. "foo"), the conversion will fail and so will your program!

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I've seen the Convert method listed when I did a quick Google search for the answer, but none of the answers actually explained what it did. I think I understand now how it works. Is there a quick and easy way for the input to adjust both integers at the same time? My current method isn't working. Not sure if I just haven't learned how to do it yet, or if I just have a type somewhere. The area in question is the commented portion.

Answer (score 1):

Just to help with an idea how to do this, try this code:

```
void Main()
{
    Dictionary<SpecialPoint, int> specialPoints = new Dictionary<SpecialPoint, int>()
    {
        { SpecialPoint.STRENGTH, 5 },
        { SpecialPoint.PERCEPTION, 5 },
        { SpecialPoint.ENDURANCE, 5 },
        { SpecialPoint.CHARISMA, 5 },
        { SpecialPoint.INTELLIGENCE, 5 },
        { SpecialPoint.AGILITY, 5 },
        { SpecialPoint.LUCK, 5 },
    };

    AskSpecialPoint(specialPoints, SpecialPoint.STRENGTH);
    AskSpecialPoint(specialPoints, SpecialPoint.PERCEPTION);
    AskSpecialPoint(specialPoints, SpecialPoint.ENDURANCE);
    AskSpecialPoint(specialPoints, SpecialPoint.CHARISMA);
    AskSpecialPoint(specialPoints, SpecialPoint.INTELLIGENCE);
    AskSpecialPoint(specialPoints, SpecialPoint.AGILITY);
    AskSpecialPoint(specialPoints, SpecialPoint.LUCK);
}

private void AskSpecialPoint(Dictionary<SpecialPoint, int> specialPoints, SpecialPoint specialPoint)
{
    int points = -1;
    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Current {0}: {1}. Adjust points: ", specialPoint.ToString(), specialPoints[specialPoint]);
    } while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out points));
    specialPoints[specialPoint] += points;
}

public enum SpecialPoint
{
    STRENGTH,
    PERCEPTION,
    ENDURANCE,
    CHARISMA,
    INTELLIGENCE,
    AGILITY,
    LUCK,
}
```